# Convert hex value of type string to byte and AND them

Tags: c#, bit

I have two values.
one string in hex. another string in binary. Have to convert the first string in binary and apply "AND" to them.

```
string mask = "2F"; // binary value of hex would be 0010 1111
string binary = "0010 0000";
```

// convert mask to binary

```
string binaryMask = ConvertToString(mask); // result must be 0010 1111;

string result = binaryMask & binary; // AND them both - result : 0010 0000
```

Comment: did you try anything? hint: convert both string to numeric values, and after that AND them. .Net has utlities for the first task, google around and you will surely find something useful

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, remove whitespace from your `binary` string (if you are not sure about input, you can remove whitespace on both strings):

```
string mask = "2F";

/* You can use "0010 0000".Trim().Replace(" ", ""); 
   to make sure there is no whitespace at beginning/end 
   of the string */
string binary = "0010 0000".Replace(" ", "");
```

Convert both values to numeric:

```
// You can use .TryParse() here, to make sure if input is valid.
var a = short.Parse(mask, System.Globalization.NumberStyles.HexNumber); 
// or var a = Convert.ToInt32(mask, 16);
var b = Convert.ToInt32(binary, 2);
```

Apply `AND` operator:

```
var c = a & b;
```

Convert the result to `string` again:

```
string result = Convert.ToString(c, 2);
```

Output:

```
100000
```

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution

```
string value = "2F";
string value2 = "00100000";

int value1Int = Convert.ToInt32(value, 16);
int value2Int = Convert.ToInt32(value2, 2);

var and = value1Int & value2Int;
var hex = and.ToString("X");
```